Why doesn't Kaiming/He weight Initialization seek a 50/50 compromise for forward and backward pass?
Sorry, please let me know if I'm off, but it seems that He initialization aims to either maintain a constant variance through the forward pass or through the backward pass.
It seems the idea is that, for a particular neuron with weights $W$ (with mean 0), for incoming values $Y$ that were either just Relu'd (if forward pass) or just dotted by Relu derivatives (if backward pass), we apply the weights $W$ to get $Y'=W \cdot Y$. This can be treated as #$W$ random vars $w_iy_i$, so since $W \cdot Y$ has mean 0 and using variance property of relu,  $Var(Y')=Var(W\cdot Y)=$ #$W 
 \cdot Var(W) \cdot \mathbb{E}[Y^2]=$ #$W \cdot Var(W) \cdot \frac{1}{2} Var[Y_{previous}]$, so we maintain $Var(Y')=1$ by choosing $Var(W)=\frac{2}{\#W}$ (and assuming $Var(Y_{previous})=1$). Here I'm treating #$W$ as the size of the structured thing that dots against values and produces a single scalar, like input/output size for forward/backward pass in MLP and whole tensor input size/output size for forward/backward in CNN.
I might likely be off, but it seems using fan_in doesn't keep a constant variance for the back pass. For example, in MLP using fan_in, (I think) the forward variance is maintained up to a constant. If we label successive inputs $Y_{1}\dots Y_{n}$, the final outputs as $O$ and use an error function such as MSE, then the first layer gradients are $\frac{2(O_{i}-C_{i})}{\#O}$, where $C$ is the correct output, and if these are treated as independent random vars with the same variance as before (since subtracting preserves variance) but scaled, then it seems we're good to go backwards with the same idea.
But up to layer $k$ the initial variance now seems to accumulate factors $\frac{\#O}{\#Y_n}\cdot\frac{\#Y_{n}}{\#Y_{n-1}}\cdots\frac{\#Y_{k+1}}{\#Y_{k}}=\frac{\#O}{\#Y_k}$. Since it seems he initialization usually uses fan_in, is it desired or intentional to have the gradient variance at layer $k$ be proportional to $\frac{1}{\#Y_k}$ during updates? If this is correct, wouldn't we want the variance to be 1 or constant? It almost seems like a compromise between the forward and backward pass might result in the same variance initialization as Xavier, (I believe) $\frac{2}{\text{fan_in}+\text{fan_out}}$? I likely made multiple mistakes or am missing something. Thank you

Ah, I think I figured the idea out. The Kaiming paper does address this. I think the idea is that, in order to train very deep networks, you want to completely maintain the variance in the forward direction and don't care about a constant factor change over each layer in backprop, whereas xavier involves a product that seeks a compromise, but doesn't completely maintain the variance in either direction, which makes it harder to accurately update very deep models
